# How to adding some zeros instead of value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Please let me know any of you know according to my problem ?

I can get value like 00000xx in oracle `using to_char(col_name ,'000000')` 
the column is number in oracle .
out will be like ;

output :  000090

I want to get same thing in MySQL how to get please tell me any of you know .
but the column is int type in mysql db. and when i retrieving  the int column in java as string format .

Thanks & Regards
Ramireddy.

Comment: post your query also

Comment: Try `SELECT LPAD(col_name, 6,'00000') FROM your_table`

Comment: Thank you a lot it's really worked

Comment: Well, update it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `concat('000000', cast(int_column as char))`

Comment: Thank you a lot for giving syntax according to my Query really it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

`SELECT LPAD(col_name, 6,'00000') FROM your_table`